# Count number of occurrences of a pattern on same line

Tags: shell-script

I need to solve this in a shell script. I am counting number of occurrence of the `abc` string below and I want to get the answer as 3.

```
echo abcsdabcsdabc | grep -o abc  
abc  
abc  
abc
```

Assuming we do not have the `-o` option in `grep`, how do we approach this then?

Comment: What shell are you using? `bash`?

Comment: If your input string is known to contain no newlines, you can just feed the output to wc `echo abcsdabcsdabc | grep -o abc| wc -l`, to count the lines.

Answer (score 4):

With `awk`:

```
awk -- 'BEGIN{print gsub(ARGV[2], "&", ARGV[1])}' abcsdabcsdabc abc
```

Note that the pattern (here `abc`) is taken by `awk` as an extended regular expression (similar to those supported by `grep -E`/`egrep`).

That syntax allows both the subject and regexp to contain multiple lines. We also avoid [the usual problems associated with `echo` which can't output arbitrary data](/q/65803).

To use `perl` regular expressions (similar to GNU `grep -P`'s):

```
perl -le 'print scalar (() = $ARGV[0] =~ m{$ARGV[1]}g)' -- abcsdabcsdabc abc
```

(note however that the arguments are not interpreted as text as per the locale's encoding. For instance in a UTF-8 locale, with  `é` and `.` as arguments, it would report 2 (bytes) instead of 1 (character)).

With `zsh`, you can do:

```
occurrences() {
  set -o localoptions -o extendedglob

  local n=0
  : ${1//(#m)$2/$((++n))}
  echo $n
}

occurrences abcsdabcsdabc abc
```

Here, the second argument (`abc`) is interpreted as a fixed string; replace `$2` with `$~2` for it to be interpreted as an extended zsh glob pattern instead (with a wider feature set than extended regexps, but a different syntax).

Answer (score 4):

Treating the string as consisting of fields that are delimited by `abc`:

```
$ echo abcsdabcsdabc | awk -F 'abc' '{ print (length > 0 ? NF - 1 : 0) }'
3
```

The number of occurrences of the delimiter `abc` is 1 minus the number of fields that it delimits.

```
$ echo abcsdabcsdabc | awk '{ n=0; while (sub("abc", "xxx")) n++; print n }'
3
```

This replaces the substring `abc` from the line with `xxx` and counts the number of times this is done, then outputs that number.  The `n=0` is not needed if there is only one line of input.

The `gsub()` function in `awk` returns the number of substitutions made, so the above could be simplified into

```
$ echo abcsdabcsdabc | awk '{ print gsub("abc", "xxx") }'
3
```

In `bash`, you can do the same thing as in that `awk` program that uses `sub()`:

```
string=abcsdabcsdabc

n=0
while [[ $string == *abc* ]]; do
    n=$(( n+1 ))
    string=${string/abc/xxx}  # replace first occurrence of "abc" with "xxx"
done
printf '%d\n' "$n"
```

This uses a `while` loop to replace the substring `abc` from the value in `$string` with `xxx` until no further occurrences of `abc` is found in `$string`, just as the second `awk` program above does.

Comment: Hi , Can u explain me on bash piece of code. not able to get how n will get value assigned to itself  when we are just dealing with single line of input. Please help to explain line wise

Comment: @Machine I've explained it further now.  The loop is looping until no `abc` is found in `$string`.

Comment: string=${string/abc/}  -- I never used this , so i believe this is inbuilt feature in unix.If u can elaborate more here

Comment: @Machine This is a `bash`-specific variable substitution that replaces the first occurrence `abc` in `$string` with nothing.  The general form is `${variable/pattern/word}` which replaces the first bit that matches `pattern` in `$variable` with `word`.  Using `${variable//pattern/word}` replaces _all_ matches.  This is described in the `bash` manual.  It is a feature of the shell, not of Unix.

Comment: Note that the first one returns `-1` for empty lines.

Comment: The second and last ones report 2 on a `ababcc` input.

Comment: `${variable/pattern/word}` is not bash-specific. It comes from ksh93 and is also supported by mksh, zsh, yash, busybox sh at least.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas All your comments are correct. Now fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
~$ echo "abcsdabcsdabc" | raku -ne '.match("abc", :global).say;'
(｢abc｣ ｢abc｣ ｢abc｣)
```

Above gives you the matches (line-by-line). Below gives you the number of matches (line-by-line):

```
~$ echo "abcsdabcsdabc" | raku -ne '.match("abc", :global).elems.say;'
3
```

Note: the `:global` argument can be shortened to `:g`.

HTH.

https://raku.org/

Answer (score -1):

Using GNU `sed`

```bsh
echo abcsdabcsdabc | sed 's/abc/abc\n/g' | wc -w
```

Comment: This gives the right answer for the example, but so does ``echo 3``.  This fails for a ***lot*** of cases, like “`xyz`” and “``The quick brown abc jumps over the lazy abc.``”